# Android - I am using camera in a Texture View. I wish to add some kind of img or text on top of the live camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, camera2

I am using camera2 in a Texture View. I wish to add some kind of image or text on top of the live camera. for eg. the way snapchat adds the time or speed on top of the live View.

[image: Example output]
when i click a picture i want to capture the live camera image as well as the text or imageview on top of the camera.
I cannot seem to find any reference online

Answer (score 0):

In theory if the base layout is a FrameLayout and then set the texture preview on the view with an index of 0, the rest of the components added after  should now be on top.